# How to change already added string column to a Reference in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I've already created a model in Rails to collect some user information

I created the columns as :string initially but I've since changed the way this data is looked up and entered by using separate populated models.

Now instead of entering into these fields as string - i want these columns to be "references" instead.

Is there an easy way to change from the string to reference without having to create a new model entirely?

*do not need to save the existing data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any data in the strings you would like to save?

Or is it just because it has the same name?

You don't have to create a new model.

You could create a simple migration

```
remove_column :table, :your_column_name, :string
add_column :table, :your_column_name, :integer, references: :your_parent_model
```

Comment: thanks, i used this to drop the fields and then re-add them. although- unless ive done something stupid, im getting a nomethoderror when trying to use the reference

Comment: my has_many / belongs_to were wrong. all sorted thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can add a temporary string column to save the string column first:

```
rails g migration add_temporary_string_column_to_model temporary_string_column:string
```

And run rails console:

```
SomeModel.all.each do |some_model|
    some_mode.temporary_string_column = some_mode.string_column
    some_mode.save
end
```

And now you can change your original string column's type to references which is an int(4) column in MySQL, migration like this:

```
class ChangeFormatInSomeTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        change_column :some_table, :string_column, :references
    end
end
```

Finally, you can run rails console again to convert the string data to integer like this:

```
SomeModel.all.each do |some_model|
    some_mode.string_column = some_mode.temporary_string_column.to_i
    some_mode.save
end
```

And at last, remove the temporary string column:

```
rails g migration remove_temporary_string_column_from_model temporary_string_column
```

Comment: thank you - i didn't need to preserve the data however

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, without dropping the column itself (not exactly in my case). I'm not sure though if this is the best solution.

In my case, I have a `tickets` table that holds `purchase_uid` in itself. I decided to keep purchases in another table after making the necessary improvements in our backend. `Purchases` table has `uuid` as the primary key. Given this background, here is my migration to change my column into a reference.

```rb
class AddPurchaseRelationToTickets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    change_column :tickets, :purchase_uid, :uuid, references: :purchase, foreign_key: true, using: 'purchase_uid::uuid'
  end

  def down
    change_column :tickets, :purchase_uid, :string
  end
end
```

In my case, since `string` doesn't automatically cast into `uuid`, `purchase_uid` were dropped and recreated as well. However, if you decide to keep the column type same, I don't think it will be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add a simpler alternative to the accepted answer that preserves data:

```
class ChangeStringToInt < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    change_column :table_name, :field_name, :integer, null: false, references: :table_referenced, using: 'field_name::integer'
    add_index :chapter_actions, :field_name
  end

  def down
    change_column :table_name, :field_name, :string, null: false, using: 'field_name::character varying'
    remove_index :table_name, :field_name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create migrations to serve the exact purpose.

```
rails generate migration AddAddressToUsers address:references
```

This will create a migration file in db/migrate directory.
Then run: `rails db:migrate` to run migration and make changes in your database.

Don't forget to create associations in your models (**belongs_to**, **has_many**, etc.) depending on your system structure.

Comment: i'm trying to replace fields that already exist that i've added to the db. they were string and im trying to undo that and make them references